# Backup Windows Azure websites

Tags: backup, azure

I have a Website on Windows Azure and I am looking for a backup solution for this website.

I am using GIT to manage source code of my website, so it easy to restore application code if something bad happens, but I am struggling with setting up some backup solution for website data (e.g. images uploaded by users)

Are there any solutions for this scenario? It would be great if Windows Backup running on another server can be setup to backup the website, but I suppose it isn't possible ...

Answer (score 1):

may be this cmdlet can help you to back it up:

```
Backup-WDApp –SourcePublishSettings <pathtopublishProfile>
```

you can also check this discussion over here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/e863867b-200d-42b5-987d-a57bc4727c1c/accessing-blob-storage-from-an-azure-website

Comment: I tried your solution and it will do the work. But I would prefer something more elegant - Backup-WDApp always copies all files, while software like Windows Backup creates incremental backups, so it can save a lot of space and a lot of time.